# Is it possible to use encrypted webservices in WP7, that do not rely on HTTPS for encryption?

Tags: windows-phone-7, soap, ws-security

I am wondering, if it is possible to use encrypted webservices in WP7, that do not rely on HTTPS for encryption? Can WP7 support the ws-security standards for encrypted SAML based XML messages, which are used in SOAP webservices?

In general, SOAP and REST are supported in WP7. JSON can be used to some extend. They all can be used encrypted with HTTPS using SSL/TLS. However I'm asking myself if its possible to encrypt the SAML messages in SOAP, so that the payload is encrypted without using HTTPS. So far this is possible using the ws-security standards.

[ws-security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security) relies on x509 certificates, which as far as I can tell, are only supported up to a certain degree in WP7. I can add certificates and trust them, either via mail or webbrowser. But I cannot use them inside my applications to enable secured connections or even authentication through certificates.

I would be really thankful, if you could provide me with links or example code for proof :)

Edit: I forgot some of the links for tutorials and tips I already read:

- [Encrypting SOAP Messages Using Web Services Enhancements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996945.aspx) - Outdated, Year 2003, but comes close to what I'm looking for, with Code Examples. But WP7 features only a subset of the used namespaces...
- [Authentication in WP7 client with REST Services–Part II](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugeniop/archive/2011/04/02/authentication-in-wp7-client-with-rest-services-part-ii.aspx) - This is just for authentication and REST services
- [Claims Based Identity & Access Control Guide](http://claimsid.codeplex.com/) - Again Access control and identity
- [Using the ASP.NET Membership Provider and Authentication Service from Windows Phone 7](http://www.kotancode.com/2010/08/06/aspnet-authentication-wp7/) - again only authentication
- [Windows Phone 7 and WS-Trust](http://www.leastprivilege.com/WindowsPhone7AndWSTrust.aspx) - ws-trust is also only a subset of ws-security. It's getting closer, but it relies on Identity Training Kit to WP7. I thought of something that does not require any external libraries
- [How to get SAML token from ADFS 2.0](http://startersts.codeplex.com/discussions/244264) - ends up in the link from above
- [Networking in Silverlight for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637320%28VS.95%29.aspx) - general information on networking and possible methods for calling methods over network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only MS API wich offers WS-Security implementation (including message level encryption, signing, X.509 Binary tokens, SAML tokens) is WCF (WSE was replaced by WCF). WCF client support for Silverlight is very limited and it doesn't support WS-Security except UserNameToken profile (= no message level encryption, signing, etc.). Support for WP7 should be same or even worse. So I guess that there is no out-of-the box support for message security because it is dependent on many other parts of .NET Framework and perhaps also on some unmanaged code. You should use HTTPS.

Btw. I also didn't see any framework supporting message level security for iPhone and Android.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the good summary. I already thought so but maybe someone would know better than me :)

I only found the [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838234(VS.95).aspx) and [Open Data Protocol - .NET/Silverlight/WP7 Libraries](http://odata.codeplex.com/releases/view/54698) but they do care only about authentication, not encryption :(

Comment: Because message level encryption is not supported by Open Data Protocol. It uses HTTPS for secured communication.

Comment: Ah ok, that is good to know. Do you know why it is not supported on the phones? I think it must be something with the encryption and its power/bandwith consumption. Or is it just because most people try to use HTTPS instead of message encryption?

Comment: IMO it is because of complexity. Message encryption is considered more "enterprise" stuff for communication between servers.